# Subgroup of a Dihedral group is Cyclic proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=D_{14}$ be the dihedral group of order 14 and let H be a subgroup of G. Suppose that $H\neq (e)$ and $H\neq G$. Prove that H is cyclic.

I'm confused on where to begin with this question, I understand that their exists some element that isn't the identity in the group and that the dihedral group is generated by 2 elements, one of order 7 and one of order 2. But how would I go about proving that H is cyclic?

Any hints/advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Lagrange's theorem, any subgroup of $D_{14}$ must have order 1, 2, 7 or 14. Orders 1 and 14 are ruled out by the question, but the remaining possible orders are prime, so any subgroup of those orders must be cyclic, as required.

Comment: Ah okay! that makes a lot of sense. How would I go about showing this mathematically though? Thanks.

Comment: @Reety What do you mean? This is already mathematical, in a sense... it is trivial to demonstrate that any prime-order group is cyclic.

Comment: how would I state Lagrange's theorem explicitly here? ( the a group of prime order is cyclic) part

Comment: @Reety Lagrange's theorem states that for any subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$, $|H|$ divides $|G|$. Certainly we are working with finite groups here.

Comment: ah okay! thank you very much (up-voted your answer; as its clear and concise).

Comment: @Reety To explicitly show that prime-order groups are cyclic: take a prime-order group. Any element in this group has order 1 or that prime, which means that either it is the identity or it is a generator for the whole group (again by Lagrange), which means that the group is cyclic (as all elements can't be the identity).

Answer (score 2):

The order of a nontrivial $H$ is prime by Lagrange, so any non-identity element must generate $H$ itself (since its order must divide $\#H$ but isn't 1).